# Capybara - Fill in form element within form using arguments

Tags: ruby, selenium, rspec, capybara

Im trying to fill in a field via its name. Because there are two fields with the same name in 2 different forms I can't just use fill_in on its own as there is an ambiguous match.

Im trying to do something like below, but obviously the within doesnt look by name, so it cannot find the form.

```
When(/^I type "(.*?)" into the "(.*?)" textbox in the "(.*?)" form$/) do |textboxValue, textboxName, textboxForm|
    within(:name, textboxForm) do
      fill_in textboxName, :with => textboxValue
    end
end
```

texboxForm - Name of the form the element is within
textboxName - Name of the textbox
textboxValue - The value I want to fill the textbox with

Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Its a bit horrible, but this worked.

```
find("form[name='" + textboxForm + "']").fill_in textboxName, :with => textboxValue
```